# How to use Web.EnsureUserByObjectId method in SharePoint Online CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, client-object-model, .net

I wasn't able to find anything about this method. Does anybody know how it works?

```
public User EnsureUserByObjectId(Guid objectId, Guid tenantId, PrincipalType principalType);
```

As I can understand from the naming it should behave in the same way as EnsureUser(string loginName) but use AD ObjectId instead of user login name, am I right?

The issue is that it always returns the error for me:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Syntax error in argument: tenantId.'
```

I tried to use my current tenant id as well as Guid.Empty, the error is always the same.